# Android usb communication activity automatic run

Tags: java, android, arduino, usb

I m Development USB Communication app ( with arduino )

when usb device attach to android phone then my app is Automatically run

i dont want Automatically run my app when usb attach

please help me

and sorry to my english skill

Comment: It is totally unclear on what basis your 'application' opperates. You should add some relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to SO.Take a two minute tour and visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

in android you can use BroadcastReceiver to detect an attached USB device, see i.e.
[[Detect USB in Broadcastreceiver - what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486339/detect-usb-in-broadcastreceiver-what-am-i-missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486339/detect-usb-in-broadcastreceiver-what-am-i-missing) or  http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-monitor-usb-events-on-android.html

usb is complex, see http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

there is the differentiation between host and device, on devices like smartphones the usb **host mode** is called usb OTG (on-the-go) and your android is the host when connected to an arduino in most cases

see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html